# Reindex with new document Id on Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I have elastic search index created through amazon kinesis to elastic search firehose. The firehose pipeline lacks the capability for adding document id and as a result the document ids are created with a unique random id. I want to perform two transformations on the new index created

1. add a document id with an existing unique field in the elastic
   search document.
2. merge the new index with an existing index.

As this is supposed to happen every 4 hrs , what is the total time needed to reindex with the new id and merge to an existing index for 100 million records on a medium ES cluster (m5.2xlarge.elasticsearch     in aws)